# Hetrogenous highlight in HTML 5

Tags: css, html

So I am trying to highlight some text in my html notes, but it fails if that highlight "region" has another tag in it see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xsv8c69e/).

I just want it to give pink bg to important text just like a real highlighter does, like [so](http://s15.postimg.org/l0l74ak9n/sample.png)

I tried `SPAN`, `MARK` & `DIV` to achieve this, but all fails.

**Note:** I understand I can enclose important text in appropriate `div`s again & again but I am looking for some way that would accomplish real-ish highlighting in one tag

HTML noob, please warn before down-voting

Comment: Your markup has issues. You close a `p` tag while `mark` is still open. Try [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Overlapping tags (`<p><mark>something</p></mark>` <-- `mark` is closed after closing `p`) are bad and should be avoided (it's something called `Tag soup` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup ). Some browsers can sometimes handle such code, but you cannot relay on this.

Comment: @antithesis I get it, please see my **Note**, I was just wondering if it could be done in a shorter way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this syntax is too bad you can't open a tag and close it inside another tag like so :

```
<p>
    lorem ipsum sit <mark class="hetro"> amet dolor
</p>

<h2> a heading </h2>

<p>
    lorem ipsum sit </mark> amet dolor
</p>
```

what you can do is applying this mark inside the other tag's too like the following :

```
<p>
    lorem ipsum sit <mark class="hetro"> amet dolor</mark>
</p>

<h2> <mark class="hetro">a heading </mark></h2>

<p>
    <mark class="hetro">lorem ipsum sit  amet dolor</mark>
</p>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xsv8c69e/1/)**

according to Wikipedia :

> "tag soup" refers to syntactically or structurally incorrect HTML
>   written for a web page. Because web browsers have historically treated
>   HTML syntax or structural errors leniently, there has been little
>   pressure for web developers to follow published standards, and
>   therefore there is a need for all browser implementations to be able
>   to treat what looks like HTML as "tag soup", accepting and correcting
>   for invalid syntax and structure.